# Measure elapsed time requestAnimFrame

Tags: javascript

How can I calculate the elapsed time the render function needs to execute once?
I would like to use this time for other functions later.
Currently I just receive time_ elapsed = 0 .

```
function render() {
    window.requestAnimFrame(render, canvas);

    time_start.getTime();
    // do rendering
    scene.render(); //here are my draw calls

    time_end.getTime();
    time_ elapsed = time_end - time_start;
    console.log(time_ elapsed);
}
```

Comment: You could look at the https://github.com/mrdoob/stats.js/blob/master/src/Stats.js code, to check if you're doing anything wrong.

Comment: Just guessing, but maybe you want to check the time elapsed from one render call to another? eg: render() { currentT = Date.now(); deltaT = currentT-prevT; scene.render(); prevT = currentT; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a typical way to do it.

```
function currentTimeInSeconds() {
  return Date.now() * 0.001;
}

var then = currentTimeInSeconds() {
function render() {
  var now = currentTimeInSeconds();
  var elapsedTimeInSeconds = now - then;
  then = now;

  scene.render();

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
render();
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using this as input to my physics engine, since this time is in ms I thought about dividing it by 1000 but doing that makes the physics incredible slow. Any suggestions? Or is it just try and error?